# CakePHP: Value from $this->request->data being lost on pagination postback

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

I have an application that takes a value from a dropdown list and uses it to filter an index view. Here is the controller code for that:

```
public function browse() {
    $this->loadModel('ReqMissionId'); 
    $missions = $this->ReqMissionId->find('list', array('fields' => array('mission_id', 'mission_id')));
    $this->set(compact('missions'));
}
```

This is the Controller code for the index:

```
public function index() {
    if($this->request->is('post')) {
        $options = array('Requirement.mission_id' => $this->request->data['Requirement']['mission_id']);
        $this->set('mission_id', $this->request->data['Requirement']['mission_id']); //Used to display the mission_id on the index page.
        $this->Paginator->settings = $this->paginate;
        $this->set('requirements', $this->Paginator->paginate('Requirement', $options));    
    }
}
```

The dropdown in the View is simple:

```
    <?php
    echo $this->Form->input('mission_id', array('label' => 'Mission ID'));
    echo $this->Form->submit(__('View'));
    echo $this->Form->end();
    ?>
```

My problem is pagination. Since Cake does a postback when it sorts the columns, the value of 'Requirement.mission_id' gets lost and I get a "Call to member function sort() on null" error. I feel like I can take care of this with a session variable, but I'm unclear on the implementation. Is that correct, or is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: Why don't you include it in the URL as a passed argument? E.g. `/controller/index/[mission_id]` and `public function index($mission_id)`

Comment: That seems elegant enough. How would I append the mission_id to the URL if pulling it from the dropdown?

Comment: By using method GET in your form, you would get a query string, which may not play nicely with pagination (you have to set `$this->paginate = array( 'paramType' => 'querystring');`  for this to work. Javascript can help you create the right URL from the dropdown for named params. However, what you really need is [CakeDC/search](https://github.com/CakeDC/search). You can filter by any field while paginating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the session for the model that you're paginating. Try something like this:

Try something like this:

```
if(!empty($this->request->data['Requirement']))
    $this->Session->write('Requirement', $this->request->data['Requirement']);
else
    $this->request->data['Requirement'] = $this->Session->read('Requirement');
```

To get it into your $options. Try use array merge like this:

```
$options = array_merge($options, $this->getOptions($this->request->data));
```

Implement getOptions under:

```
function getOptions($data = null){
            $options = array();

            if(!empty($data['Requirement']['mission_id']))
                $options = array_merge($options, array('mission_id' => $data['Requirement']['mission_id']));

            return $options;
    }
```